# Jacobian matrix between a 2-dimensional space and a 3-dimensional space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Imagine that there is a disk in 2-dimensional space $(x',y')$, and a bump in 3-dimensional space $(x,y,z)$ whose projection is just the disk. There is a transformation between these 2 spaces with a known Jacobian matrix
\begin{equation}
  \Lambda_{2\times3} = \left[
  \begin{matrix}
    \frac{\partial x'}{\partial x } & \frac{\partial x'}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial x'}{\partial z} \\
    \frac{\partial y'}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial y'}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial y'}{\partial z}
  \end{matrix} \right].
\end{equation}

My question is, how to get the value of components of the Jacobian matrix
\begin{equation}
  \Lambda_{3\times2} = \left[
  \begin{matrix}
    \frac{\partial x}{\partial x'} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial y'} \\
    \frac{\partial y}{\partial x'} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial y'} \\
    \frac{\partial z}{\partial x'} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial y'} \\
  \end{matrix} \right]
\end{equation}
of the inverse transformation from $\Lambda_{2\times3}$?

Another question is, how to calculate the determinant for the Jacobian matrices between spaces of different dimensions? I think there is a possible expression $|\Lambda_{3\times2} \cdot \Lambda_{2\times3} |$, but I am not sure whether it makes sense and what geometric meaning does it have.